# get background color of spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner, onlongclicklistener

I have a bunch of spinners whose background color i need to TOGGLE on a long click.
The background color can be either green or red.
If red, then change to green, and vice versa.

I have registered a long click listener, but in the onLongClick function, I do not know how to get the current background color of the spinner so I can compare it and change it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean,

```
public boolean isRed;
public boolean isGreen;
```

and then once they click it just set that those to true or false then use a logic statement like

```
if(isRed) {
  //CHANGE TO GREEN
  isRed = false;
  isGreen = true;
} else {
  //CHANGE TO RED
  isGreen = false;
  isRed = true;
}
```

You can use a switch on your onClick

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.spin1:
        case R.id.spin2:
        case R.id.spin3:
        case R.id.spin4:
        case R.id.spin5:
        case R.id.spin6:
            if(isRed) {
                //CHANGE TO GREEN
                isRed = false;
                isGreen = true;
            } else {
            //CHANGE TO RED
                isRed = true;
                isGreen = false;
            }
            break;
      }
}
```

Comment: I have many spinners, so I need to associate those variables with every spinner. How do I do that? And how do i access these variables from inside the onLongClick function?

Comment: I still do not understand, where is the isRed and isGreen initialized? I am also changing the color in another module... Also, doing that saves only the state of ONE spinner, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, guys.
I used setTag and getTag as:

```
spin.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
spin.setTag(Color.GREEN);
```

and then,

```
if((Integer) spin.getTag() == Color.RED)
{
    //again change color to green and set tag like above
}
else //change color to red and set tag
```

Worked like a charm ^_^